# Git integration with Jupiter Lab?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

Now that `jupyterlab-git` does not work with the latest Jupyter Lab / Notebook, is there an alternative? I don't see anything on the roadmap of either that would indicate future plans for supporting Git integration (likewise for `nbdime` which is flagged as incompatible as well).

Comment: Others may want to know that [the issue page on Github](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/1245#issuecomment-1690195633) indicates it is actively being worked on with recent commits in particular addressing the `nbdime` issue.

Comment: @Wayne That would be an answer I'd accept if you want to write it up (saw the issue but the 4.0 threw me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JupyterLab 4 introduced some hiccups. The extensions from 3 need some work.

[The issue page on Github](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/1245#issuecomment-1690195633) indicates it is actively being worked on with recent commits in particular addressing the `nbdime` issue.

Some suggest sticking with JupyterLab 3.6.3 for now while it is fixed.